# Regex - Match all subsections

Tags: regex, pcre

I have the following strings which indicate a hierarchy:

```
JHW/1/24/3/562 // child row
JHW/1/24/3     // parent of the above
JHW/1/24       // parent of the above
JHW/1          // parent of the above
JHW            // parent of the above
```

What I'd like to do is to be able to pull out all of the "parent" rows with one regex.

The closest I've got conceptually (which isn't anywhere near) is `#^([^/]*/)+#` which just matches the second-last section [eg. 3].

I've never really tried to do something like this before, where I'm trying to get overlapping results - it is possible? It's not an issue if it brings back the child row as one of the matches.

Comment: Overlapping results are not a problem, but you can't obtain several  results from the same position. If you use PHP, explode the string with `/` and deal with the array.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte If you want to put that into an answer, I'll accept it soon, unless someone else can come up with a workaround :-)

Comment: To whoever decided this is "too broad" and downvoted to close, I really can't understand what gives you a kick. It's a very specific question and if you need anything more specific, maybe you just shouldn't be trying to help people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't obtain several results from the same position (since the regex engine go to the next character after each try of the pattern), you can explode the string with `/` and build each path you need with the array items.

An other possible way consists to reverse the string:

```
preg_match_all('~(?=(?:\A|/)(.+))~', strrev($path), $m);

$result = array_map('strrev', $m[1]);
```